# Not receiving Firebase Cloud Messaging delivery receipts

Tags: node.js, firebase, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am sending the following message through fcm xmpp client. But I am not getting delivery receipt for the delivered messages.

I am using `node-xcs` node package for sending XMPP message.

```
var Sender = require('node-xcs').Sender;
var Message = require('node-xcs').Message;
var Notification = require('node-xcs').Notification;
var Result = require('node-xcs').Result;
var xcs = new Sender('123', 'xxxx', 1);
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');
xcs.on('message', function(messageId, from, data, category) {
    console.log('received message', arguments);
}); 


xcs.on('receipt', function(messageId, from,  data, category){
    console.log(messageId,'dsafdsafdsaf')
});

xcs.on('connected', function(){console.log('connected')});
xcs.on('disconnected', function(){console.log('disconnected')});
xcs.on('online', function(){console.log('online')});
xcs.on('error', console.error);
xcs.on('message-error', function(){console.log('message-error')});

var notification = new Notification("./logo.png")
    .title("Hello buddy!")
    .clickAction("https://github.com/guness/node-xcs/blob/master/google/Notification.js")
    .body("test_body")
    .build();

var message = new Message(uuidv4())
    .priority("high")
    .dryRun(false)
    .deliveryReceiptRequested(true)
    .notification(notification)
    .build();

xcs.sendNoRetry(message, 'token', function(result) {
    if (result.getError()) {
        console.error(result.getErrorDescription());
    } else {
        console.log("message sent: #" + result.getMessageId());
    }
});
```

Below is the XMPP message sent from the package

```
<gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">{
  "to": "token",
  "message_id": "59171fc6-42ad-4f22-812f-d0c4f7fa63d0",
  "priority": "high",
  "delivery_receipt_requested": true,
  "notification": {
    "body": "test_body",
    "click_action": "https://github.com/guness/node-xcs/blob/master/google/Notification.js",
    "icon": "./logo.png",
    "title": "Hello buddy!"
  }
}</gcm>
```

I am getting `ack`, but I am not getting Delivery receipt, Why is the delivery receipt not coming even if the message is delivered?

Comment: I am doing something here that I usually warn others from doing - trying to resolve a problem without even being familiar with the basics of the domain :) where are you expecting the delivery receipt? On the console of the GCF stdout?

Comment: `console.log(messageId,'dsafdsafdsaf')`, I want the delivery receipt of the message, which can i use for marking message is delivered.

Comment: node-xcs works with node.js version <= 11. It does not work with 12 and 13 unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

[node-xcs](https://github.com/guness/node-xcs) is based on the works of [node-gcm-ccs](https://github.com/jacobp100/node-gcm-ccs) and it's not properly maintained.
See disclaimer in the last of [node-xcs](https://github.com/guness/node-xcs)
You can not even send notifications to ios Devices as it was only build to support sending FCM to android and web devices.

See [here](https://github.com/jacobp100/node-gcm-ccs), it says that it's not maintained in very bold letters.
*I recommend using [fcm-push](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fcm-push) instead of using node-xcs*

Last year I had faced similar issues with this library and I switched to fcm-push after reading these very bold messages of "NOT MAINTAINED NOT MAINTAINED NOT MAINTAINED".